# Tap to translate in own application

Tags: android, google-translate

For my application I want to make some sort of 'tap to translate' option. Just like Google translate. I only want to know how to implement the pop-up feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the "Tap to Translate" by drawing over other apps. For that request the `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission.

Please refer this [Medium post](https://medium.com/@rotxed/drawing-over-other-apps-marshmallow-edition-987eff9f99a9).